# How to do a database backup in DB2 in Vista?

Tags: db2, authorization, database-restore, udb-db2, database-backup

How to do a database backup in DB2 in Vista?

Whenever I issued this command (login in Vista as `Administrator`):

```
restore database myDB from D: taken at 20081013134446
```

the command line processor return the following error message:

```
SQL1092N  "ADMINISTRATOR" does not have the authority 
to perform the requested command.  SQLSTATE=00000
```

So, How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run the restore command as user that does not have enough priviledges. Probably easiest solution for you would be to use the SYSADM priviledges.

First, check under which account the DB2 services are running. If the answer is SYSTEM, please change that into something sensible (for instance Administrator) from Services (you can find it in Control Panel). Then restart the services.

After that log in using *that* user account, and the restore command will work.